# How to fix "Unable to load schema" in package.json for React app?

Tags: reactjs, schema, package.json

I'm getting an error under the first bracket in my package.json and a problem with a message that reads: "Problems loading reference 'https://json.schemastore.org/package': Unable to load schema from 'https://json.schemastore.org/package': Request vscode/content failed unexpectedly without providing any details." Any info on what could have went wrong and how to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

there could be multiple reasons for this like a bad internet connection or if the schema has been cashed already then this could cause a problem also.
a good solution for this is to specify a local schema to your project.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
  "name": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "version": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "description": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "main": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "type": "object"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "type": "object"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "type": "object"
  }
  },
  "required": ["name", "version"]
}
```

save this file to your project root directory as **package.schema.json** or just copy [the remote schema](https://json.schemastore.org/package), and add this line to your **package.json** file

```
"$schema": "./package.schema.json",
```

and this should fix the problem.